# Is there any way to use MongoOpeations in a springboot application which is configured with two mongo databases

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

I have done a sample application with springboot to connect with two databases using the below reference
https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mongodb-connectors-with-spring-boot

I can access data from different databases using repository interfaces which extends MongoRepository
But i want to access data using MongoOperations as below how to differentiate between two databases

````
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
public class SampleController {

    private final PrimaryRepository primaryRepository;
    private final SecondaryRepositor secondaryRepository;


    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOps;

    @Autowired
    public SampleController(PrimaryRepository primaryRepository, SecondaryRepositor secondaryRepository) {
        this.primaryRepository = primaryRepository;
        this.secondaryRepository = secondaryRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void sample() {
        log.info("************************************************************");
        log.info("Start printing mongo objects");
        log.info("************************************************************");
       primaryRepository.save(new PrimaryModel(null, "Primary database plain object"));

        secondaryRepository.save(new SecondaryModel(null, "Secondary database plain object"));

        List<PrimaryModel> primaries = primaryRepository.findAll();
        for (PrimaryModel primary : primaries) {
            log.info(primary.toString());
        }

        List<SecondaryModel> secondaries = secondaryRepository.findAll();
        **List<SecondaryModel> second =   mongoOps.findAll(SecondaryModel.class);**
        log.info("RES: {}",second);
        for (SecondaryModel secondary : secondaries) {
            log.info(secondary.toString());
        }

        log.info("************************************************************");
        log.info("Ended printing mongo objects");
        log.info("************************************************************");

    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Qualifier` to get desired MongoDB instance.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("primaryMongoTemplate")
MongoOperations primaryMongoOps;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondaryMongoTemplate")
MongoOperations secondaryMongoOps;
```

**Note:**

You don't need `public SampleController(PrimaryRepository primaryRepository, SecondaryRepositor secondaryRepository)`, use instead:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    PrimaryRepository primaryRepository;

    @Autowired
    SecondaryRepositor secondaryRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("primaryMongoTemplate")
    MongoOperations primaryMongoOps;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondaryMongoTemplate")
    MongoOperations secondaryMongoOps;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void sample() {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two MongoOperations bean. You can replace replace `localhost` with the DB machine IP Address. if you have sharded cluster you can change below implementation `new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://host1:27017,host2:27017"));`

```
@Configuration
class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() {
        return new MongoClient("localhost", 27017); // server address, port
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("firstDatabase")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "test1Db"); // test1Db is database name 
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("secondDatabase")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "test2Db");
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, you can inject both `MongoTemplate` and connect to the respective database.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("firstDatabase")
MongoOperations mongoOps1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondDatabase")
MongoOperations mongoOps2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below configuration to use multiple database with MongoOperation
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.company.repo.dbOne"}, mongoTemplateRef="mongoTemplateOne")
public class AbcRepoConfiguration {

```
@Bean(name="mongoPropertiesOne")
@ConfigurationProperties
public MongoProperties mongoProperties() {
    return new MongoProperties();
}

@Bean(name="mongoPropertiesOne")
public SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory(MongoClient mongo, @Qualifier("mongoPropertiesOne") MongoProperties mongoProperties) throws Exception {
    String database = this.mongoProperties.getMongoClientDatabase();
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, database);
}

@Bean(name="mongoTemplateOne")
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Qualifier("mongoTemplateOne") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter converter) throws UnknownHostException {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
}
```

}
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.company.repo.dbTwo"}, mongoTemplateRef="mongoTemplateTwo")
public class AbcRepoConfiguration {

```
@Bean(name="mongoPropertiesTwo")
@ConfigurationProperties
public MongoProperties mongoProperties() {
    return new MongoProperties();
}

@Bean(name="mongoPropertiesTwo")
public SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory(MongoClient mongo, @Qualifier("mongoPropertiesTwo") MongoProperties mongoProperties) throws Exception {
    String database = this.mongoProperties.getMongoClientDatabase();
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, database);
}

@Bean(name="mongoTemplateTwo")
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Qualifier("mongoTemplateTwo") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter converter) throws UnknownHostException {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
}
```

}